# Postgres: why do some function calls require () and others not?

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

My question is this:
Why do some postgresql functions require an empty bracket and others don't and how can I tell the correct syntax?

Examples:
This does not work

```
select pg_postmaster_start_time;
```

results in

```
ERROR:  column "pg_postmaster_start_time" does not exist
LINE 1: select pg_postmaster_start_time;
           ^
```

However this works:

```
select pg_postmaster_start_time();
```

resulting in

```
   pg_postmaster_start_time
-------------------------------
 2016-08-01 16:07:12.728306+01
(1 row)
```

Now for the converse case: This works

```
select current_user;
```

and it results in

```
 current_user
--------------
 edbstore
(1 row)
```

But this does not work

```
select current_user();
```

Resulting in

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 1: select current_user();
                       ^
```

I did find this has been asked [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20021129010833.1CFB.RK73@sea.plala.or.jp), but there didn't seem to be an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html) - it says

> Note: current_catalog, current_schema, current_user, session_user, and
>   user have special syntactic status in SQL: they must be called without
>   trailing parentheses. (In PostgreSQL, parentheses can optionally be
>   used with current_schema, but not with the others.)

I know it sounds like "because it says so", so does not actually answer your question. But this is how docs explain it.

Comment: Yes, this is a standards-compliance thing. The SQL standards have acquired bits and pieces from the various big systems over the years and perhaps lack elegance.